# Existe algum plugin ou gerador de código CSS para Shapes(Formas)?

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber se há um método de criar Shapes(Formas) utilizando CSS, do qual eu não precise ficar criando e ajustando tudo na mão desde o zero, até conseguir criar a forma que eu desejo.

Existe alguma maneira de agilizar isto? Algumas formas padrões ou algum gerador/plugin que realize parte ou todo este trabalho pra mim?

**Eu não desejo adicionar várias shapes, e sim algumas ocasionalmente, logo, a ferramente seria para agilizar meu trabalho, e não para automatiza-lo.**

Comment: Tem que ser CSS, necessariamente?

Comment: Você acha que CSS não é recomendado para este caso?

Comment: Não sei se o mais recomendado ou não, mas, caso você queira gerar vários shapes, parece mais uma tarefa "programacional", do que uma tarefa de design (estilo).

Comment: Vou ajustar a pergunta, no meu caso são shapes que eu faço ocasionalmente, e não vários deles, a função é não fazer eu perder tempo.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi.

Comment: Não sei se é esse tipo de coisa que você procura: http://www.createjs.com/#!/CreateJS

Comment: @bfavaretto cara, me pareceu bem interessante onde tem exemplos disto? só achei pra download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paulo você pode utilizar o [CSS Shape Generator](http://www.samuelrossille.com/css-shape/), ele está em beta ainda mas é muito útil e parece ser o que você precisa.

Comment: Cara, perfeito!! exatamente o que eu queria, queria saber como eu não achei isso antes...

Answer (score 3):

Não conheço uma ferramenta específica para isso, mas creio que o [Google Web Designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/) pode ajudar a agilizar o processo te dando uma interface grafica para isso.

Comment: é interessante, parece ser algo bem profissional, mas assim, ele gera código CSS?

Comment: Sim, ele gera o HTML e CSS para tudo.

Comment: Muito interessante, vou baixar ele em casa hoje à noite e vou dar uma olhada, me lembrou muito um velho amigo meu, o Adobe Flash Pro =p

Comment: Concordo, ele me lembrou muito também, só que agora da forma certa ^^

Comment: Realmente, porque ele se tornou obsoleto mediante as forças do trio Javascript+html+css e foi daí que mudei de paixão de Flash para Javascript kkk